# jQuery : Kill Mouseenter/mouseleave function on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issues with mouseenter/mouseleave function.

please take a look at my code;

```
$(".elms").live(
{
    mouseenter: function (e) 
    {
        $("a").click(function()
        {
            alert('test');
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) 
    {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

html :

```
<div class='elms'>test [ function says `test` ]</div>
<div class='elms'>test [ function says `test` and `test` ]</div>
<div class='elms'>test [ function says `test` and `test` and `test` ]</div>
<div class='elms'>test [ function says `test` and `test` and `test `test` and `test` ]</div>
```

and this will repeat for even 90 elements , i want to kill function on leave and make new one. Something like this :

```
var killIt = $(".elms").live(
{
    mouseenter: function (e) 
    {
        $("a").click(function()
        {
            alert('test');
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) 
    {
        killIt.die();
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

[ Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/29f3P/ ]

Comment: Your fiddle link is incorrect

Comment: Also, `live` has been deprecated for a while now...

Comment: I modified your fiddle, seems to be working as you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, in this case you are adding a listener each time you mouse over the .elms element.  If you truly want to add a listener each time you mouse over and you don't want the repeated behavior you are seeing can use bind and unbind to set your mouse events as described [here:](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$(".elms").live({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
             $("a").bind("click", function(){
                  alert('test');
             });

        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
             $("a").unbind("click");

        }
```

});

I modified your fiddle [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/29f3P/1/)

Comment: yes, it works. but i have NO IDEA why not working in real code , the real code have some many connection with other variables in other javascript files , i can not post that here

Comment: It might be the selector you are using...a is very generic..i'd probably do somthing like $("div.elms > a")

Answer (score 0):

If you must destroy the listener each time, try jQuery.one(), which will destroy the listener automatically after the first call.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

If the listener does not necessarily run one time, try jQuery.off() to unbind the listener.

http://api.jquery.com/off/